# Binary to Gray code using XOR boolean expressions

Tags: boolean-algebra, binary

I have a question which asks to design a circuit to convert from binary to gray code, using a boolean expression.

Now I understand you have to use XOR to achieve this. And I understand that XOR means that only one or the other can be true, if both are true thats just nomral OR.

I also understanding how to convert between gray code and binary and vise versa through addition, with this video: [Binary to Gray code video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOhPycZeVpw&index=9&list=PLV8l9mFhj1w1ixWOf_YIW0uwb7HnJyeVr)

I'm just having trouble understand how to do this using XOR. Below is the task I've been set and they've gave me some examples to start with, but I don't understand them.

If anyone could explain to me how these examples work I would be greatful.

[Image of my task and some examples of boolean expressions using XOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AycKS.png)

Comment: Can you tell us what "gray code" means?

Comment: Well i can link you this if that helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

Comment: That doesn't excuse you from including it in your question. Help people help you. Otherwise, the more you make people google stuff to understand your question, the more you require them to click on links, the fewer people who will help.

Comment: Well I would have thought that people who are anwering the question already know what the Gray code is. I can't explain it myself so I have to give links. I just want the question answered not this pointless bickering.

Comment: Gray code is a resequencing of a set of binary numbers, so that in the new sequence, progressing from one member of the sequence to the next, the difference between any two consecutive members is only in one bit position. See the following: $$\matrix{0000&0000\cr0001&0001\cr0010&0011\cr0011&0010\cr0100&0110\cr0101&0111 \cr0110&0101\cr0111&0100\cr1000&1100\cr1001&1101\cr1010&1111\cr1011&1110\cr1100&1010\cr1101&1011\cr1110&1001\cr1111&1000}$$

Comment: I edited Senex' comment. The array environment is not available in the comments, so I replaced it with a `\matrix` - a similar but slightly limited construct from the plainTeX era. Any TeX-snippet of more than 80 characters may also create problems. The system will then insert extraneous whitespace characters. You can see some in the edited comment. At least it's legible now :-)

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/425894/11619) for an explanation of a particularly simple Gray code. I also warmly recommend everything Dilip Sarwate has posted about these. For example [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/965388/11619).

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen \ As always, Dr. Lahtonen, you bend over backwards to be helpful. Thank you for reworking my comment. I didn't know what the heck was wrong.

Comment: Just a comment : I think it is not a "pointless bickering" just for one reason (Personaly, I know what Gray code is) had you written "gray" with a capital "G" : instead, understand that a confusion can occur "a **gray** code" = "some **secret** way of coding but which one ???"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the 4-bit example in the above comment.
Standard binary to Gray code:
$a\mid b\mid c\mid d\qquad\to\qquad p\mid q\mid r\mid s$
where
$p=(a)$
$q=(a\not\equiv b)$
$r=(b\not\equiv c)$
$s=(c\not\equiv d)$
$====================$
Gray code to Standard binary:
$p\mid q\mid r\mid s\qquad\to\qquad a\mid b\mid c\mid d$
where
$a=(p)$
$b=(p\not\equiv q)$
$c=(p\not\equiv q\not\equiv r)$
$d=(p\not\equiv q\not\equiv r\not\equiv s)$
The XOR $\not\equiv$ operation is associative, so the order in which these multiple XORs are performed is immaterial.

Comment: what does the three lines with the line through mean?

Comment: @GR412 \ It's one of the several ways of expressing the exclusive-or operation. It is generated as follows: \not\equiv

Comment: Maybe $\oplus$ is a more common symbol for XOR.